# scaled_float being presented as string

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have several indexes of type `scaled_float`. The problem is that when I realize a search, those indexes are presented as string instead of numeral.

on my elasticsearch document model I have the following:

```
indexes :price, type: 'float', index: false
```

and when I get to search, the result comes this way:

```
...,
"price": "89.00"
```

but I wanted to be

```
"price": 89.00
```

Is it possible?